# How to use this switch function so that it does what I need it to do

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
void regame1(int k) //Funcion para el redo
{
char redo;
char response2;
unsigned int o;

printf("Quieres volver a sacar las cartas para el jugador1?\n"); 
printf("Aprete (s = si, n = no)\n");
scanf("%s", &redo); //Poner el char redo en el scanf
if (redo == 's')
{
    printf("Que posicion de cartas te gustaria cambiar? (Maximo hasta 3)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &response2);
    while (( response = getchar())!= EOF)
    {
        switch (response2)
        {
            case '1':
            hand1[0] = cards[20]; symbol[0] = symbols[20];
            break;
            case '2':
            hand1[1] = cards[21]; symbol[1] = symbols[21];
            break;
            case '3':
            hand1[2] = cards[22]; symbol[2] = symbols[22];
            break;
            case '4':
            hand1[3] = cards[23]; symbol[3] = symbols[23];
            break;
            case '5':
            hand1[4] = cards[24]; symbol[4] = symbols[24];
            break;
            case '\n':
            case '\t':
            case ' ':
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Las cartas nuevas del jugador 1 son:\n");
    for (o = 0; o <= 4; o++)
    {
    printf("%s%s  ", letters[hand1[o]], symbol[o]);
    }
}
```

}

So I have my function but every time I press 1 or 2 or 3 after the scan, it doesn't do any of them or it does only one of them, switching the hand1 array or the symbol array :(

Am I doing anything wrong? I just want it so that if the user presses 1, it'll do what is in case '1', and at the end just press ctrl + d to break out.

Comment: Is `response` in while condition a typo ?

Comment: oops yeah, i had another global variable called char response but just fixed it. It still doesn't do it the way i want it to though T_T

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is `response` reads the `newline` left in the input buffer after the user presses `[enter]` after providing a value:

```
scanf(" %c", &response2);
while (( response = getchar())!= EOF)
```

You need to fix the `scanf` so you are consuming the newline:

```
scanf(" %c%*c", &response2);
```

You will then be able to get a value to `response`. If you want to prove this to yourself, just add a `switch` clause that responds to `'\n'`.

To solve the issues, you will also need to repeatedly flush the `newline` from the input buffer on each loop. Give me a few minutes and I'll drop an example. (got to pick up daughter...)

Ok, back. If I were setting this up to use `scanf` and make sure there was no way I could leave a `'\n'` in the `input buffer` and have the `switch` behave as expected, I would use a simple `character buffer`, read the input **as a string**, and the pass a `pointer` to the first character to the `switch` statement as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char buf[8] = {0};

    printf ("\nQue posicion de cartas te gustaria cambiar? (Maximo hasta 3, [enter] to exit)\n");

    while ( printf ("\n response: ") && scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", buf) == 1 )
    {
        switch (*buf)
        {
            case '1':
                printf ("  hand1[0] = cards[20]; symbol[0] = symbols[20];\n");
            break;
            case '2':
                printf ("  hand1[1] = cards[21]; symbol[1] = symbols[21];\n");
            break;
            case '3':
                printf ("  hand1[2] = cards[22]; symbol[2] = symbols[22];\n");
            break;
            case '4':
                printf ("  hand1[3] = cards[23]; symbol[3] = symbols[23];\n");
            break;
            case '5':
                printf ("  hand1[4] = cards[24]; symbol[4] = symbols[24];\n");
            break;
            default:
                printf ("  error - invalid input\n");
            break;
        }    
    }

    printf ("\n All done!, bye...\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/nonewln

Que posicion de cartas te gustaria cambiar? (Maximo hasta 3, [enter] to exit)

 response: 1
  hand1[0] = cards[20]; symbol[0] = symbols[20];

 response: 2
  hand1[1] = cards[21]; symbol[1] = symbols[21];

 response: 3
  hand1[2] = cards[22]; symbol[2] = symbols[22];

 response: 4
  hand1[3] = cards[23]; symbol[3] = symbols[23];

 response: 5
  hand1[4] = cards[24]; symbol[4] = symbols[24];

 response: 6
  error - invalid input

 response:

 All done!, bye...
```

Comment: Hmm that's weird I still can't get to seem to make it work. I also tried out various things and if i press only '1', it won't do anything but change the symbols[] but not the hand1[] part....

Comment: Why do you `scanf` response, then immediately `response=getchar()` which changes the value?

Comment: oh that was a typo I mistyped, I fixed it to response2 = getchar() right after posting this

Comment: @Seung, I am back. I put together a quick example of a safer way to approach getting the input your wanted with `scanf`. Here the `newline` is always consumed and if no input is provided, the `while` loop is exited. While I generally recommend reading input as a line with `fgets` or `getline`, this is one instance where `scanf` works equally well.

Comment: I actually have a question though, was this done to print the hand1[0] = cards[20] etc. etc.?
My problem was that I just wanted to equal the element hand1[0] to the cards[20] if 1 was pressed.
Also, I'm sorry for the beginner question but it stops right after I press 's' in the if condition. Is there a reason why?
Sorry for all the trouble, I'm kind of learning to program like 3 months ago *-*

Comment: It was just an example. I just stuck `printf` in front of your code to show you it was correctly handling the input and to create output to validate that it was. Just use your code instead of the `printfs` inside the switch